# I cannot find my schedule for system shut down

Tags: shutdown, cron, schedule

Long time ago I set a schedule for shutting down the system at a particular time. Now I need to change this time but I cannot find this schedule anywhere.

I checked crontab and gnome-schedule

Does anyone know other places or software in which I might have this schedule on ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/
```

there should be a file for every user that is allowed to and has a crontab

```
crontab -l -u username => list the jobs set for that username
crontab -e -u username => edit the jobs for that username
crontab -r - u username => remove the jobs for that username
```

Comment: I've checked there but there were no files there :(

Answer (score 0):

You must have scheduled the shutdown via some third party software. While there are many such available, you may track down your one by checking them up from the installed packages list using following command -

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

Some popular shut down software include - [Complex Shutdown](https://launchpad.net/complexshutdown) and [Easy Shutdown](http://www.launchpad.net/easyshutdown)